# PHP multi-threading and returning values to parent thread

Tags: php, multithreading

I have been at this for over an hour, I have read everything under the sun about multi-threading in PHP, and I am lost when it comes to returning values to the parent thread. I have been practically brute forcing different combinations of ways I can come up with to pass variables back to the parent thread with zero success. I am not even sure if it is possible at this point.

I have tried static classes/methods/vars with a return, callbacks, anonymous methods, invokes, and nothing is working, I continue to get an empty array when the code finishes executing.

Attempt 1) I created a class called Results, with a static method that assigned a value to a static var array, with another static method to return all of the data when the code was finished executing, a print_r showed the data being added to the static var array, however, when the script was finished executing the static processData method returned an empty array.

Attempt 2) I removed the static elements from the Results class, and placed it in the TaskManager, using an anonymous method as a callback, I was able to return values to the TaskManager, but again, when the code was finished executing, an empty array.

Attempt 3) I created a global anonymous method to use as a callback, again, values are passed to the callback method, but you guessed it, empty array when the code was finished executing.

I am listing three attempts, but really, its been more like 20 attempts at this; I am at my wits end, any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I have been working with.

```
<?php

/**
 * author : Marc Quinton / April 2008.
 *
 *  a simple task management framework using pcntl_fork, pcntl_wait.
 *
 *  - see at bottom for a sample usage.
 *  - you shoud overring Task class (SleepingClass is an example), and manage them in a pool, using taskManager
 */

error_reporting(E_ALL);

class Results {
    var $datas = array();

    public function data($data)
    {
        $this->datas[] = $data;
    }

    public function processResults()
    {
        foreach($this->datas as $data)
        {
            print_r($data);
        }
    }
}

class Task {

    protected $data;

    protected $pid;
    protected $ppid;

    function __construct(){
    }

    function fork(){
        $pid = pcntl_fork();
        if ($pid == -1)
            throw new Exception ('fork error on Task object');
        elseif ($pid) {
            # we are in parent class
            $this->pid = $pid;
            # echo "< in parent with pid {$his->pid}\n";
        } else{
            # we are is child
            $this->run();
        }
    }

    function run(){
        # echo "> in child {$this->pid}\n";
        # sleep(rand(1,3));
        $this->ppid = posix_getppid();
        $this->pid = posix_getpid();
    }

    # call when a task in finished (in parent)
    function finish(){
        echo "task finished {$this->pid}\n";
    }

    function pid(){
        return $this->pid;
    }
}

class SleepingTask extends Task{
    public $mybl;
    public $data;
    public $cback;

    function __construct($bl, $cb){
        $this->cback = $cb;
        $this->mybl = $bl;
    }

    function run(){
        global $callback;

        parent::run();

        echo "My BL ID: " . $this->mybl . " /END BL ID\n";

        $callback(array('whoa' => $this->mybl));

        sleep(rand(1,2));

        exit(0);
    }
}

class TaskManager{

    protected $pool;
    protected $datas = array();

    function __construct(){
        $this->pool = array();
    }

    function add_task($task){
        $this->pool[] = $task;
    }

    function run(){

        foreach($this->pool as $task){
            $task->fork();
        }

        # print_r($this);
        # sleep(60);

        while(1){
            echo "waiting\n";
            $pid = pcntl_wait($extra);
            if($pid == -1)
                break;

            echo ": task done : $pid\n";
            $this->finish_task($pid);
        }

        echo "processes done ; exiting\n";
    }

    function finish_task($pid){
        if($task = $this->pid_to_task($pid)) {
            $task->finish();
        }
    }

    function pid_to_task($pid){
        foreach($this->pool as $task){
            if($task->pid() == $pid)
                return $task;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

$datas = array();
$callback = function ($data) {
    print_r($data);
    global $datas;
    $datas[] = $data;
};

$manager = new TaskManager();

for($i=0 ; $i<10 ; $i++)
    $manager->add_task(new SleepingTask($i, $callback));

$manager->run();

print_r($datas);

exit(0);

?>
```

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant, but `$extra` is undefined in `TaskManager::run()`.

Comment: @halfer Aparently it is okay to do that when [passing by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

Comment: @Havenard, good spot. Nevertheless, my IDE complains, and personally I would set it to null prior to the call anyway.

Comment: The problem here is that you can't share the data between your parent and child process. They're different and can't see each others' data or structures. Had these been threads, you could synchronize/join them. That's why PHPs' [Thread](http://us1.php.net/Thread) might be of use to you. If you want to share data between N processes, you need to implement a mechanism for them to communicate - shared memory, file that they access by acquiring locks, database or similar. Or simply - use actual threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run your code, and your callback is being called successfully each time. However, it's worth bearing in mind that this is multi-*process*, not multi-threading. That means that for each item added to the array, the global array is brand new on each occasion, and so when you add a new item, there is only one item in there after each push.

Furthermore, each of those additions occurs in a child process, so when control reverts to the parent process, the global array there is also new, and so there is correctly nothing in it.

There are a few solutions here:

- Use a database for your results
- Use some other shared storage mechanism, e.g. the filing system or Memcache
- Use an inter-process communication system, such as [Semaphore](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sem.php). I've not used this, but it might be of interest - ideally you want to send messages to a specific PID (the parent task)

Personally, I'd use a database, since this is a convenient mechanism to retrieve it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a look at **socket_create_pair()**.

In the PHP manual is a very short & easy example of interprocess communication (IPC) between a fork()-parent and the child.

And using **serialize()** und **unserialize()** You could even transfer complex data types like arrays...